# How do I get EF Core to automatically populate values in an entity's child object using a repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

How do I get EF Core to automatically populate values in an entity's child object from the look up table using a repository?

```
public class JobTask
{
      [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FuelType")]
        public int StatusID { get; set; }
        public StatusObj JobStatus { get; set; }
}

 public class StatusObj
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id  { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

To be clear, the status table in the database is just a look up table. The status table has an ID and a Description. The jobtask table hold a fk reference to the id in the status look-up table. One JobTask can only have one status at any one time.

But whenever a row for a jobtask is requested, how do I get ef core to automatically populate the Status object on the JobTask object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying your `JobTask` from your DatabaseContext you need to include the StatusObj like this:

```
_context.JobTask.Include(jobTask => jobTask.JobStatus).ToList();
```

for more details check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)